# Loop is running more than specified in C? Why?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

If I enter the number 5, this loop has to run 5 times but it is running 6 times. What is the problem?

```
 int main(){
        int i, *arr, size;
        printf("Please enter the Number: ");
        scanf("%d ",&size);
        arr = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
            scanf("%d ", &arr[i]);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Did you check the value of size before the loop?

Comment: try removing space after %d in loop scanf.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove the trailing space from the `scanf()` format string being used in the loop.

It causes scanf() to discard all whitespace after having read an `int` (`%d`), until it finds something that is not whitespace.    On the fifth iteration of the loop, `scanf()` reads the `int`, and keeps going until it finds non-whitespace.   This gives the illusion of needing to read one more integer.

On the last call of `scanf()`, any non-whitespace character after the integer data will cause reading to end.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the space here:

This:

```
 scanf("%d ",&arr[i]);
          ^
```

should be:

```
 scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
```

Comment: Yes it is working. But what is the problem?

Comment: It's related to [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) which is quite complicated. Don't bother for the moment.

Comment: Please can you please give me the source so that i can go and read? I am curious to know about it.@Michael Walz

Comment: @Muralikrishna A whitespace character in the format string of `*scanf` instructs `*scanf` to read and discard any number of whitespace characters, if any, **until the first non-whitespace character**. So, your `scanf`, after the fifth iteration, waits for a non-whitespace character, as the bolded part above says.

Comment: @Muralikrishna click on "scanf" in my previous comment. This will open a page for the complete documentation of scanf.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the similar problem. To get it perfect please remove the
space after **%d**  in the loop. It should work. Might be some property of `scanf`.

```
int main(){
        int i, *arr, size;
        printf("Please enter the Number: ");
        scanf("%d",&size);// Note the change here
        arr= (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        for(i= 0;i < size;i++){ 
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But what is the problem? can you please explain.

Comment: @Cool Guy Some one edited the code.Now it is proper.